# Median of 3 partitioning

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I found the following code for finding a pivot for quicksort using median of first, last and middle element:

```
int middle = ( low + high ) / 2;
if( a[ middle ].compareTo( a[ low ] ) < 0 )
    swapReferences( a, low, middle );
if( a[ high ].compareTo( a[ low ] ) < 0 )
    swapReferences( a, low, high );
if( a[ high ].compareTo( a[ middle ] ) < 0 )
    swapReferences( a, middle, high );

// Place pivot at position high - 1
swapReferences( a, middle, high - 1 );
Comparable pivot = a[ high - 1 ];
```

I want to know after finding the median, why is the swap done with index high-1 instead of high?

Comment: Just making a guess. Correct me if I am wrong. Your `high` could be the length of the array and your `high-1` could be the last value of the array. For calculation of the median, the `high(lastindex+1)` wouldn't make a difference but for swapping it does. Could you please post the entire program to find the real reason.

Comment: i will post the whole code, but just to let u know, high is the last index and the length of the array

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the algorithm does not only find the median, it also sorts the low, middle and high elements. After the three permutations you know that a[middle]<=a[high]. So you need only to partition the elements before high, because a[high] is greater or equal to pivot.

Let's look at an example: low=0, middle=4 and high=8. Your array is like this:

```
lowerOrEqualToPivot X X X pivot X X X greaterOrEqualToPivot
```

If you swap middle with high, you need to partition the 8 elements between brackets :

```
[ lowerOrEqualToPivot X X X greaterOrEqualToPivot X X X ] pivot
```

If you swap middle with high-1, you need to split only 7 elements:

```
[ lowerOrEqualToPivot X X X X X X ] pivot greaterOrEqualToPivot
```

By the way there is a bug in the first line:

```
int middle = ( low + high ) / 2; //Wrong
int middle = ( low + high ) >>> 1; //Correct
```

The reason is that if (low + high) is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE you will have an overflow and middle will be a negative number. The second line will always give you a positive result.