# How does using >>> 1 prevent overflow when adding two numbers than dividing by 2?

Tags: java, quicksort, bit-shift

I've seen in a few [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144484/median-of-3-partitioning) the following code recommended to add to numbers and divide by 2, particularly in the context of finding a middle index in an array to be quicksorted.

`int middle = ( low + high ) >>> 1;`

opposed to
`int middle = ( low + high ) / 2;`

Correct me if I'm wrong on the basics. Right shifting bits 1 position (`>> 1`) has the effect of dividing by 2. Since in java `int` is signed we don't want to change the first bit, so we use the unsigned shift operator `>>>`. I've heard the claim this prevents integer overflow but I don't see how. According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) arithmetic operators have presidence over shifts. Which is a moot point since brackets are being used anyways. If whatever's in the the `( )` overflows why would something outside matter?

Comment: Actually, if your number is negative `>>>` will *change* the leading bit because it always shifts in a 0, thus making negative numbers positive again. I don't think this is a way of preventing integer overflow, rather it seems like a way of working around it. Curious to see if this actually works...

Comment: Now that I think about it, that would mean that this won't work for two negative numbers, as the result will always be positive. There might need to be an additional constraint, such as one (or both) numbers being positive...

Comment: @user3580294 that trick is for when both number are non-negative, yes. Essentially it "steals" the signbit as the "extra bit" to hold the 1-bit-wider temporary result.

Comment: @user3580294 yes, in the context of finding the median value of 3 elements of an array, it makes sense to only be talking about positive numbers i.e. indexes of an array.

Comment: @harold Ah, that makes sense. Didn't quite get it, but it clicked when you explained it that way. Thanks!

Comment: @Celeritas Yeah, missed the link the first time around, so didn't notice that it was supposed to be used for indices. My mistake.

Comment: It doesn't prevent overflow of the `(low + high)` but using `>>> 1` means the result of that will not be overflowed. e.g. Consider `x + 1 - 1` The result of `x + 1` can overflow, but the result of `x + 1 - 1` will not overflow.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I guess I assumed overflow would throw an exception or cause UB or do something the program couldn't recover from.

Comment: @Celeritas A common assumption, but it just pretends it didn't happen and it is left to you to deal with it.

Answer (score 9):

When you add two `int`s, the number may overflow into a negative number, but the bits are still there, and no information is lost; it could be interpreted as an unsigned `int`, if Java had such a type.  Let's try to average 2^30 and 2^30 + 2 with this method.

```
  01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
+ 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
  -----------------------------------
  10000000 00000000 00000000 00000010  // overflow
```

In Java, this would be interpreted as -2^30 + 2, but if it were unsigned, then it would be interpreted as 2^31 + 2.

Java's unsigned bit-shift-right operator, `>>>`, shifts in a zero instead of sign-extending.

```
  10000000 00000000 00000000 00000010  >>> 2 yields
  01000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

And that's the correct answer, 2^30 + 1.

That is contrast to the signed bit shift operator, `>>`, which sign-extends:

```
  10000000 00000000 00000000 00000010  >> 2 yields
  11000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

That's incorrect, -2^30 + 1.

This will work for averaging two positive `int` values.  But because the result will always be non-negative, this won't work if the correct average value is negative.

Real example:

```
int low = 0x40000000;
int high = 0x40000002;

int unsigned = (low + high) >>> 1;
int signed = (low + high) >> 1;

System.out.println("low     =" + low);
System.out.println("high    =" + high);
System.out.println("unsigned=" + unsigned);
System.out.println("signed  =" + signed);
```

The output:

```
low     =1073741824
high    =1073741826
unsigned=1073741825
signed  =-1073741823
```

Comment: So `x >> y` shifts x's bits y positions to the right but 1)doesn't change the first first bit of x (as it's the sign) 2)the bits added after the first bit have the same value of the sign. What I'm saying is, I'm unclear if 0s are 1s are added? Is it whatever the sign is?

Comment: With `>>`, the bit(s) that is(are) shifted in is(are) the same as the existing sign bit, so that negative numbers stay negative when shifted to the right.  With `>>>`, `0` bit(s) is(are) always shifted in.

Comment: Ok and in contrast `<<` always shifts in 0s? This seems strange to me.

Comment: `<<` does always shift in zeroes, because it's equivalent to multiplying by a power of 2.  `x << y` is equivalent to the mathematical expression "x * 2^y".  It doesn't makes sense to define a `<<<` operator that shifts in a `1` in the least significant bit, because that adds `1` to the result.  What would be the purpose in allowing `3 <<< 1`, which would result in `7`?

Comment: Ok thanks. One other thing is I noticed `>> 1` has the effect of dividing by 2 and rounding down. How do you know that it always rounds down in terms of looking at the bits?

Comment: Any bits that are shifted "off" the right side represent what would be binary fractions that are simply dropped.  Those dropped bits are effectively rounding down to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is a typo:

```
    >> 2
```

should be:

```
    >> 1
```

and

```
    >>> 2
```

should be

```
    >>> 1
```

for the shift operator examples...